# Сравнение "похожих" строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Имеется вот такая модель инвентаря:

```py
class Inventory(BaseModel):

    type = models.ForeignKey(
        InventoryType, verbose_name='Наименование инвентаря',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Инвентарный номер')
    date_begin_use = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Дата ввода в эксплуатацию',
        validators=[MinValueValidator(date(1900, 1, 1))],
    )
    date_end_use = models.DateField(
        null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name='Дата списания',
        validators=[MinValueValidator(date(1900, 1, 1))],
    )
    reason_stop_using = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True, null=True,
        verbose_name='Причина списания',
    )
```

У него есть поле code - Инвентарный номер. Этот инвентарный номер должен быть уникальным, но тут есть одно НО.

Пример инвентарного номера - ***K35***. Неясно, русская здесь *K* или английская. Так вот, нужно сделать проверку, которая будет при сохранении проверять новый инвентарный код на уникальность, при этом также исключая возможность сохранить "похожий" номер.

У меня, собственно, не получается придумать такой алгоритм, который производил бы такое сравнение, при этом не нагромождая код кучей костылей

Comment: Можно ограничить допустимый набор букв только латиницей, или только кириллицей

Comment: Можно попробовать алгоритм Расстояние Дамерау — Левенштейна, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/152bcc77cec844676b022640e27601270eeb0626/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance__misprints__%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/simple_distance_Levenshtein/match_two_words.py#L7

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в код параметр `unique`. Получится:

```
code = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Инвентарный номер', unique=True)
```

Английская `K` и русская `К` имеют разный символьный код, т.е. система выдаст вам `False` при сравнении.

Если на страницу выводите инфу через джанговские формы, то можете ещё и в форме сделать валидацию вводимых данных: https://djbook.ru/rel1.5/ref/forms/validation.html

**UPD.ver.1.** Костыль через валидацию. При этом в БД должны быть коды только с символами одного языка, т.е. нельзя в одном инв.номере иметь и русские, и английские буквы. Ну и желательно, чтобы символы в инв.номерах были одного кейса: только заглавные или только строчные. Не факт, что будет работать, но мысль должна быть понятна.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import re

def my_validator(value):
    status = 0
    rus_val = re.findall(r'[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+', value)
    eng_val = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', value)

    if rus_val:
        status = 1
    if eng_val:
        status = 2

    letters_rus = {'А' : 'A', 'В' : 'B', 'Е' : 'E', 'К' : 'K', 'М' : 'M', 'Н' : 'H', 'О' : 'O', 'Р' : 'P', 'С' : 'C', 'Т' : 'T', 'Х' : 'X'}
    letters_eng = {'A' : 'А', 'B' : 'В', 'E' : 'Е', 'K' : 'К', 'M' : 'М', 'H' : 'Н', 'O' : 'О', 'P' : 'Р', 'C' : 'С', 'T' : 'Т', 'X' : 'Х'}

    replica = ''

    if status == 1:
        for element in value:
            if element.upper() in letters_rus:
                replica += letters_rus[element.upper()]
            else:
                replica += element.upper()
    elif status == 2:
        for element in value:
            if element.upper() in letters_eng:
                replica += letters_eng[element.upper()]
            else:
                replica += element.upper()        

    if Inventory.objects.filter(code=value).exists() or Inventory.objects.filter(code=replica).exists():
        raise ValidationError(u'%s уже существует!' % value)

class Inventory(BaseModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Инвентарный номер', validators=[my_validator])
```

**UPD.ver.2.** Переопределить метод `save`. Тот же костыль, но внутри модели.

```
class Inventory(BaseModel):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Инвентарный номер')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        status = 0
        rus_val = re.findall(r'[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+', self.code)
        eng_val = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', self.code)

        if rus_val:
            status = 1
        if eng_val:
            status = 2

        letters_rus = {'А' : 'A', 'В' : 'B', 'Е' : 'E', 'К' : 'K', 'М' : 'M', 'Н' : 'H', 'О' : 'O', 'Р' : 'P', 'С' : 'C', 'Т' : 'T', 'Х' : 'X'}
        letters_eng = {'A' : 'А', 'B' : 'В', 'E' : 'Е', 'K' : 'К', 'M' : 'М', 'H' : 'Н', 'O' : 'О', 'P' : 'Р', 'C' : 'С', 'T' : 'Т', 'X' : 'Х'}

        replica = ''

        if status == 1:
            for element in self.code:
                if element.upper() in letters_rus:
                    replica += letters_rus[element.upper()]
                else:
                    replica += element.upper()
        elif status == 2:
            for element in self.code:
                if element.upper() in letters_eng:
                    replica += letters_eng[element.upper()]
                else:
                    replica += element.upper() 

        if super(Inventory, self).objects.filter(code=self.code).exists() or super(Inventory, self).objects.filter(code=replica).exists():
            raise Exception('{} уже существует!'.format(self.code))
        else:
            super(Inventory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Вы внимательно читали вопрос?) K большая английская и K большая русская должны восприниматься как одно и то же - вот в чём суть. Если я добавлю unique=True, то я всё равно смогу сохранить две записи с инвентарным номером K35, используя русскую и английскую буквы.

Comment: Да, пардон, упустил этот момент) Должно сохранять русскую или английскую версию?

Comment: Можно сохранять хоть русские, хоть английские символы. Но если например в системе есть K35 с английской К, то К35 с русской сохранить уже нельзя, и наоборот.

Comment: @AntonMalyarov зачем так усложнять? не проще разрешить ввод только или русских или английских

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin это не моя личная прихоть, и не университетская задача. Я обсуждал уже этот вопрос с аналитиками - сказали сделать именно так.

Comment: @AntonMalyarov А что делать с буквами 'В', 'H', 'Х', 'P' ? Тот же принцип? Ибо они обозначают разные звуки в русском и английском.

Comment: @AlioshcaZ еще буквы М O A T. т.е уже 9 букв и у всех разные кодировки. Не понятно как автор хочет обойтись тут без куче костылей